# How to reconnect when a WebSocket is closed with RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, websocket, rtk-query

I'm trying to make a websocket connection with rtk query.
My code creates a new connection when the socket is closed.
When websocket is reconnected, the data in useGetMessageQuery is not updated.

**ChatApi Code :**

```
let ws: WebSocket;
let interval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>;
export const init = () => {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
  ws.onopen = (message: Event) => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'keepAlive' }));
    }, 1000 * 15);
  };
  ws.onclose = (message: CloseEvent) => {
    interval && clearInterval(interval);
    setTimeout(() => {
      init();
    }, 1000 * 10);
  };
}

export const chatApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getMessages: build.query<any, any>({
      queryFn: () => ({ data: {} }),
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        arg,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded
          const listener = (event: MessageEvent) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              draft.push(data)
            })
          }

          ws.addEventListener('message', listener)
        } catch {
        }
        await cacheEntryRemoved
        ws.close()
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetMessagesQuery } = chatApi;
```

**Using message data in a component :**

```
const { data: message } = useGetMessagesQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  init();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(message);
}, [message]);
```

Is there a way to update data when a socket is reconnected?
Or is there another way to reconnect when the websocket is closed using rtk query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset the API state when the websocket reconnected and this worked.
This method worked for me. Now, the status of rtk-query changes normally even after the websocket is reconnected.
I hope this answer helps someone.

**ChatApi Code :**

```
let ws: WebSocket;

export const init = (socket: WebSocket) => {
  ws = socket;
}

export const chatApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getMessages: build.query<any, any>({
      queryFn: () => ({ data: {} }),
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        arg,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded
          const listener = (event: MessageEvent) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              draft.push(data)
            })
          }

          ws.addEventListener('message', listener)
        } catch {
        }
        await cacheEntryRemoved
        ws.close()
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetMessagesQuery, useLazyGetMessageQuery } = chatApi;
```

**Using message data in a component :**

```
export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [getMessage, { data: message }] = chatApi.useLazyGetMessage();

  const initChat = () => {
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

    ws.onopen = (message: Event) => {
      getMessage();
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'keepAlive' }));
      }, 1000 * 15);
    };
    ws.onclose = (message: CloseEvent) => {
      interval && clearInterval(interval);
      dispatch(chatApi.util.resetApiState());
      setTimeout(() => {
        initChat();
      }, 1000 * 10);
    };

    init(ws);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initChat();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message);
  }, [message]);
};
```